# View of extended nebulae from HST

Tags: optics, astronomy, telescopes

I studied that f-stop has a effect on brightness of an extended objects in telescope. If f-stop is high the area over which image of extended object spread is high and brightness is low. So my doubt is that can Hubble telelecope with f-stop 24 can produce bright images of extended nebulae clearly than one in ground with less f-stop like 3 or not?

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind here is that in space, there is no atmosphere, so the scattered light that would wash out extremely dim objects on terrestrial telescopes doesn't exist.

Comment: [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Not relevant to the question about HST, but there are some very unusual, very optically fast (low focal ratio) telescopes out there. [Dragonfly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5473)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with producing sharp pictures of nebulae is the spatial resolution of the camera. The number of arcseconds per pixel is around 0.05 for the HST cameras at their f-ratio. This is done to approximately match the superb point spread function that can be achieved when not looking through the blurring effect of the Earth's atmosphere (note that the transmissivity of the Earth's atmosphere is not really an issue at visible wavelengths).

Since the angular size of the pixels is small and since HST is quite a small telescope, then HST needs to perform long (cumulative) exposures to get its best images.

If the f-ratio were decreased then HST pixels would cover a larger angle and its field of view would be wider. Yes, there would then be more light per pixel, but unfortunately the pixels would not sample the point spread function properly and the images would look just as blurred as through ground based telescopes.

Note that adaptive optics on ground based telescopes can and does get around the blurring of Earth's atmosphere. However these techniques work only in the infrared, whereas most of HST's spectacular images of nebulae are at the wavelength a of prominent optical emission lines.

Answer (score 0):

A ground telescope will be limited by the aberrations caused by turbulence in the atmosphere. Nowadays we have adaptive optics with very high power lasers to get around that, but a space telescope is outside the atmosphere and doesn't have to worry about that.

As for the HST itself, if you wanted to decrease the f/# you'd have to decrease the focal length or increase the entrance pupil diameter. Sending a bigger telescope to space would increase cost and a shorter focal length would increase mirror complexity. That trade-off starts to get pretty complicated and expensive.

Comment: The transmission of the earth's atmosphere at visible wavelengths is of order 90%.

Comment: I don't know all the detectors on the HST but they at least go from UV to 2.5 micron. There are a couple bands in there that drop out. Since we're discussing space trelescopes vs ground and the JWST goes out to 28 micron, I thought it was relevant.

Comment: Most pictures of nebulae are in optical emission lines.

Comment: Ah, ok. Editing.